# Send email on softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

In Softlayer Portal, I ordered email delivery service. and i can see it at list. but how can send email with java api.

I tried to send email with below code.

```
Email email = new Email();
email.setfrom();
email.setBody();
email.setTo();
Boolean result = service.sendEmail(email);`
```

but it show error that is "ID is required to invoke service"

if you share a sample code, it will be helpful as well.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To use the sendEmail method, it is necessary to specify a init parameters (SoftLayer_Network_Message_Delivery_Email_SendgridInitParameters) you can see this in **"Required Headers"** section from the [SoftLayer_Network_Message_Delivery_Email_Sendgrid::sendEmail](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Message_Delivery_Email_Sendgrid/sendEmail) method, you can get more information about init parameters [here](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/using-initialization-parameters-softlayer-api).

So, You can get "SoftLayer_Network_Message_Delivery_Email_Sendgrid" objects using the following method: [SoftLayer_Account::getNetworkMessageDeliveryAccounts](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkMessageDeliveryAccounts), here a Rest request:

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkMessageDeliveryAccounts

Method: Get
```

You will get a result like this:

```
0:  {
"accountId": 123456
"createDate": "2015-05-15T06:35:56+12:00"
"id": 24564
"modifyDate": "2016-01-08T05:59:57+11:00"
"password": "Password123*"
"typeId": 21
"username": "newemail@softlayer.com"
"vendorId": 1
"emailAddress": "email@softlayer.com"
"smtpAccess": "1"
}
```

So, you need to specify the "id" in the service that you are using (SoftLayer_Network_Message_Delivery_Email_Sendgrid). It should look like this in java:

```
Long sendGridId = new Long(24564);
Sendgrid.Service sendgridService = Sendgrid.service(client, sendGridId);
```

It doesn't work fine for me, it seems the SoftLayer API Client for Java has an issue to specify init parameters for "SoftLayer_Network_Message_Delivery_Email_Sendgrid" service. You can verify it and submit an issue if you are not able to specify this [SoftLayer API Client for Java Issues](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java/issues).

In fact, I can provide a rest request which is working fine:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Message_Delivery_Email_Sendgrid/24564/sendEmail

Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "body":"set me",
         "from":"set me",
         "to":"set me",
         "subject":"set me"
      }
   ]
}
```

References:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Message_Delivery_Email_Sendgrid/sendEmail